# p:schedule rounded hours

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar, schedule

I want to show schedule rows with the rounded hours (7:00) and time range (7:00-7:30). Primefaces version 8.
It is possible schedule component?
    My component:

```
<p:schedule id="schedule" 
  extender="initSchedule"
  value="#{idopontController.eventModel}" 
  widgetVar="myschedule"
  view="timeGridWeek" 
  locale="#{idopontController.locale}"
  timeZone="#{idopontController.timeZone}"
  clientTimeZone="#{idopontController.clientTimeZone}"
  rightHeaderTemplate="timeGridWeek"
  showWeekends="#{idopontController.showWeekends}"
  tooltip="#{idopontController.tooltip}"
  allDaySlot="#{idopontController.allDaySlot}"
  slotLabelInterval="#idopontController.slotLabelInterval}"
  scrollTime="#{idopontController.scrollTime}"
  minTime="#{idopontController.minTime}"
  maxTime="#{idopontController.maxTime}"
  columnHeaderFormat="#idopontController.columnHeaderFormat}"
  initialDate="#{idopontController.initialDate}"
  timeFormat("HH:mm{ - HH:mm}"
>
</p:schedule>
```

Comment: Are you looking for slotLabelFormat? [Docs](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedulehttps://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedule)

Comment: Please also add your version info to the question

Comment: My primefaces version :8.

Comment: I agree it sounds like slotLabelFormat is probably what you need, although your description of which thing you want to change is not very clear. Perhaps a screenshot would help.

Comment: slotLabelFormat is not available in primefaces 8 :(

Comment: Really? It should be. It's a standard property of fullCalendar. I would be surprised if they implement all the other properties and not that one. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: P.S. Am I right in thinking that this is the correct documentation page for this primefaces component: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedule ? Because slotLabelFormat is clearly listed there....

Comment: @ADyson: it is..

Comment: Last try, this time with the correct link I hope, have you try with [axisFormat](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/schedule) (PF <= 7)?